# Django manage.py --no-input . Yes or no?

Tags: django, django-manage.py

I can't find this in the docs. When I run `python manage.py collecstatic --no-input` does it mean it will answer "yes" to any prompt that would pop up in the process? The same for `python manage.py migrate --no-input`.

Comment: I think generally, it's to answer `yes`, but I've noticed before bugs with it failing to remove stale content types.   https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25036

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For collectstatic:

```
    message.append(
        'Are you sure you want to do this?\n\n'
        "Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: "
    )

    if self.interactive and input(''.join(message)) != 'yes':
        raise CommandError("Collecting static files cancelled.")
```

So for collect static, if you set `--no-input` it will set `interactive` to `False` and, as you can see above, will answer `yes` to the question for you.

For migrate it is much trickier because of django signaling.  The `migrate` management itself does not ask any questions, but other installed apps may hook into the `pre_migrate_signal` or `post_migrate_signal` and handle interactivity in their own way.  The most common one I know of is `contenttypes`

For `contenttypes`, `--no-input` answers "no" as in "No, please don't delete any stale contenttypes":

```
        if interactive:
            content_type_display = '\n'.join(
                '    %s | %s' % (ct.app_label, ct.model)
                for ct in to_remove
            )
            ok_to_delete = input("""The following content types are stale and need to be deleted:

%s

Any objects related to these content types by a foreign key will also
be deleted. Are you sure you want to delete these content types?
If you're unsure, answer 'no'.

    Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: """ % content_type_display)
        else:
            ok_to_delete = False
```